# Inseting asynchronous messages into JSF2 facelet

Tags: jsf, jms

I'm trying to develop a simple chat application using JSF2, Message Driven Beans and JMS.

I followed [this](http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/example-of-messageBean.shtml) tutorial and all works great.
The issue is that I have no idea how can I insert asynchronously something from a ManagedBean into a JSF facelet.

I know that PrimeFaces and other have chat implementation but this project has an self educational purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: how does "educational purpose" conflicts with using an already implemented push solution of primefaces for example?

Comment: @Daniel well the reason I'm doing this is to find out how to do this kind of things without using an existing library.

Comment: ooo... self educational purpose... I thought its being developed for some edu customer...

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it is a personal project.

Answer (score 0):

If you mainly want to do this for self education, why not study the source code of rich- and primefaces push? Those two are both open source, so the code is readily available.

There's also an article by someone from the Mojarra team about this topic, see https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/jsf_and_html_5_intersection